# Column 'Artiuclulo' cannot be null

Tags: java, sql, spring

**estoy haciendo un crud con angular y spring lo que pasa al momento de querer almacenar los datos me aparece la leyenda Column 'Artiuclulo' cannot be null eh revisado la base de datos y tengo todo al igual el código. Accedo a la base de datos y borro los not null y funcina espero recibir su ayuda

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Artiuclulo' cannot be null
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~

**

Persona.java

```
package com.example.backend;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "inve")
public class Persona {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column
    private int sku;

    @Column
    private String Artiuclulo;
    
    @Column
    private String Marca;
    
    @Column
    private String Modelo;

    @Column
    private int Departamento;

    @Column
    private int Clase;

    @Column
    private int Familia;

    @Column
    private String Fecha_Alta;

    @Column
    private String Stock ;

    @Column
    private String Cantidad;

    @Column
    private int Descontinuado;
    
    @Column
    private String Fecha_Baja;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getSku() {
        return this.sku;
    }

    public void setSku(int sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    public String getArtiuclulo() {
        return this.Artiuclulo;
    }

    public void setArtiuclulo(String Artiuclulo) {
        this.Artiuclulo = Artiuclulo;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return this.Marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String Marca) {
        this.Marca = Marca;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return this.Modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String Modelo) {
        this.Modelo = Modelo;
    }

    public int getDepartamento() {
        return this.Departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(int Departamento) {
        this.Departamento = Departamento;
    }

    public int getClase() {
        return this.Clase;
    }

    public void setClase(int Clase) {
        this.Clase = Clase;
    }

    public int getFamilia() {
        return this.Familia;
    }

    public void setFamilia(int Familia) {
        this.Familia = Familia;
    }

    public String getFecha_Alta() {
        return this.Fecha_Alta;
    }

    public void setFecha_Alta(String Fecha_Alta) {
        this.Fecha_Alta = Fecha_Alta;
    }

    public String getStock() {
        return this.Stock;
    }

    public void setStock(String Stock) {
        this.Stock = Stock;
    }

    public String getCantidad() {
        return this.Cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(String Cantidad) {
        this.Cantidad = Cantidad;
    }

    public int getDescontinuado() {
        return this.Descontinuado;
    }

    public void setDescontinuado(int Descontinuado) {
        this.Descontinuado = Descontinuado;
    }

    public String getFecha_Baja() {
        return this.Fecha_Baja;
    }

    public void setFecha_Baja(String Fecha_Baja) {
        this.Fecha_Baja = Fecha_Baja;
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package com.example.backend;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;



@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/personas"})
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    PersonaService service;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Persona>listar(){
        return service.listar();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Persona agregar(@RequestBody Persona p){
        return service.add(p);
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/{id}")
    public Persona listarId(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return service.listarId(id);
    }  
    
    @PutMapping(value="/{id}")
    public Persona editar(@RequestBody Persona p, @PathVariable("id") int id){
        p.setId(id);
        return service.edit(p);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Persona delelte(@PathVariable("id")int id){
        return service.delete(id);
    }
}
```

PersonaServiceImp.java

```
package com.example.backend;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonaServiceImp implements PersonaService{

    @Autowired
    private PersonaRepository repository;

    @Override
    public List<Persona> listar() {
       return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Persona listarId(int id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Persona add(Persona p) {
        return repository.save(p);
    }

    @Override
    public Persona edit(Persona p) {
        return repository.save(p);
    }

    @Override
    public Persona delete(int id) {
        Persona p = repository.findById(id);
        if(p != null){
            repository.delete(p);
        }
        return p;
    }
 

}
```

PersonaRepository.java

```
package com.example.backend;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

public interface PersonaRepository extends  Repository<Persona, Integer>{

    List<Persona>findAll();
    Persona findById(int id);
    Persona save(Persona p);
    void delete(Persona p);

}
```

PersonaService.java

```
package com.example.backend;

import java.util.List;

public interface PersonaService {
    
    List<Persona>listar();
    Persona listarId(int id);
    Persona add(Persona p);
    Persona edit(Persona p);
    Persona delete(int id);

}
```

listar.html

```
<div class="container col-md-6" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Agregar</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display:inline-block; ">
                    <label for="">SKU:</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.sku" name="" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-check col-md-6" style="display:inline-block; ">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.Descontinuado" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Descontinuado</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Articulo:</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.Artiuclulo" name="" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Marca:</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.Marca" name="" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Modelo:</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.Modelo" name="" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Departamemto:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option selected>Elige una opcion</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Departamento" value="1">1</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Departamento" value="2">2</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Departamento" value="3">3</option>
                      </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Clase:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option selected>Elige una opcion</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Clase" value="1">1</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Clase" value="2">2</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Clase" value="3">3</option>
                      </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Familia:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option selected>Elige una opcion</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Familia" value="1">1</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Familia" value="2">2</option>
                        <option [(ngModel)]="persona.Familia" value="3">3</option>
                      </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display:inline-block;">
                    <label for="">Stock:</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.Stock" name="" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display:inline-block;">
                    <label for="">Cantidad:</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.Cantidad" name="" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display:inline-block;">
                    <label for="firstName" class="form-label">Fecha Alta:</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.Fecha_Alta" type="date" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display:inline-block;">
                    <label for="firstName" class="form-label">Fecha Baja:</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="persona.Fecha_Baja" type="date" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </form>
            <button (click)="Guardar()" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 10px;">Guardar</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Persona.ts

```
export class Persona{
    constructor(){}
    id:number;
    sku:number;
    Artiuclulo:String;
    Marca:String;
    Modelo:String;
    Departamento:number
    Clase:number;
    Familia:number;
    Fecha_Alta:Date;
    Stock:String;
    Cantidad:String;
    Descontinuado:number;
    Fecha_Baja:Date;
}
```

database

```
create table inve(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    sku int NOT NULL,
    Artiuclulo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Marca varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Modelo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Departamento int NOT NULL,
    Clase int NOT NULL,
    Familia int NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Alta varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Stock varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Cantidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Descontinuado int NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Baja varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: El código parece estar bien... estás seguro de que estás rellenando el campo con algún valor?? Porque obviamente si lo marcas como `not null` luego nunca puedes dejarlo en blanco... Los campos que no sean obligatorios no deberían llevar `not null` si no un `default X`, por ejemplo :)

Comment: si los estoy llenando bien estoy llenando el formulario todo sin dejar nada vacio y al momentod e darle click al boton  me arroja el error

Comment: Pues lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas un problema en tu método `guardar()` en la parte del front... justo el único método que no podemos ver de todo el flujo.

Comment: El del fronto lo tengo así

Comment: Guardar(){
    this.service.createPersona(this.persona)
    .subscribe(data=>{
      alert("se agrego con exito");
      this.router.navigate(["listar"]);
    })
  }

Answer (score 1):

En tu tabla estás definiendo que la columna `Artiuclulo` sea `NOT NULL`, quiere decir que cuando la columna reciba valores `NULL` éste te tirará error. Tendrías que permitir que la columna pueda contener valores tipo `NULL` o vacíos, esto lo solucionarías cambiándolo por `NULL`, ya nos cuentas si te ha funcionado:

```
create table inve(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    sku int NOT NULL,
    Artiuclulo varchar(255) NULL,
    Marca varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Modelo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Departamento int NOT NULL,
    Clase int NOT NULL,
    Familia int NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Alta varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Stock varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Cantidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Descontinuado int NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Baja varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: lo intente como dijiste ahora lo que me pasa esque al momento de almacenar datos la base de datos los datos estan con el valor de cero y no con los datos correctos

Comment: De seguro el error sería al enviar los datos.

Comment: Mira esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698167/column-cannot-be-null-mysql